# How to compare month in obiee?

Tags: oracle, plsql, business-intelligence, obiee

How to write this case statement in obiee?

```
CASE WHEN to_char(to_date(hire_dt, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'Month') <> to_char(to_date(start_dt-1, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'Month') THEN 1 Else 0
```

Month not equal:

Example:

```
0   -> 09/14/2021   09/16/2021
1   -> 12/31/2019   03/15/2017
```

Comment: What is the data type of the `hire_dt` and `start_dt` columns? And, do you want to compare month and year (i.e. `2020-09-14` is not the same month as `2019-09-16`) or do you just want to compare month (i.e. `2020-09-14` and `2019-09-16` are both September and are the same month)?

Comment: The data type of the hire_dt and start_dt are date. I only want to compare month. If same month then 0 if different month then 1

Comment: But, what does "same month" mean? Same month and year? Or same month of any year?

Comment: Don't use `TO_DATE` on dates. This will implicitly convert them to a string and then convert them back to a date and if your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter does not match the format model you are using then your query will raise an exception.

Comment: Same month of any year. I just want to compare month regardless of the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to compare month regardless of the year.

In Oracle:

```sql
CASE
WHEN EXTRACT( MONTH FROM hire_dt ) = EXTRACT( MONTH FROM start_dt )
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

or

```sql
CASE
WHEN TO_CHAR( hire_dt, 'MM' ) = TO_CHAR( start_dt, 'MM' )
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

This [OBIEE Date functions documentation](https://datacadamia.com/dat/obiee/obis/date) suggests you can use `MONTH`:

```sql
CASE
WHEN MONTH( hire_dt ) = MONTH( start_dt )
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```